# Fix Tabcontrol Tabpage location in tabs

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol

I have a TabControl in Winforms that I can Remove a tabpage with a button via the code :

```
            TabControl1.Tabpages.Remove(TabPage1)
```

however, when I add the tabpage again using this code

```
            TabControl1.Tabpages.Add(TabPage1)
```

the tabpage gets added in after the last tabpage.

How do I restore the ORIGINAl location of the tabpage in the tabControl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll have to store the original index so that you know where to put it back to:

```
index = TabControl1.TabPages.IndexOf(TabPage2)
...
...    
TabControl1.TabPages.Insert(index , TabPage2)
```

Comment: Understood, will try it asap.